# What does --> (dash dash greater than) operator means in Swift

Tags: swift

I look at the source code of [GPUImage2](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2/blob/master/examples/iOS/SimpleImageFilter/SimpleImageFilter/ViewController.swift)

```
    picture = PictureInput(image:UIImage(named:"WID-small.jpg")!)
    filter = SaturationAdjustment()
    picture --> filter --> renderView
    picture.processImage()
```

What does `-->` do?

Comment: It's specific to that package, it's not a "general" Swift thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an operator declared to add a destination target to the source.

```
infix operator --> : AdditionPrecedence
//precedencegroup ProcessingOperationPrecedence {
//    associativity: left
////    higherThan: Multiplicative
//}
@discardableResult public func --><T:ImageConsumer>(source:ImageSource, destination:T) -> T {
    source.addTarget(destination)
    return destination
}
```

The function is declared in the `pipeline.swift` file

The `addTarget` function is also pretty self descriptive.

```
public func addTarget(_ target:ImageConsumer, atTargetIndex:UInt? = nil) {
    if let targetIndex = atTargetIndex {
        target.setSource(self, atIndex:targetIndex)
        targets.append(target, indexAtTarget:targetIndex)
        transmitPreviousImage(to:target, atIndex:targetIndex)
    } else if let indexAtTarget = target.addSource(self) {
        targets.append(target, indexAtTarget:indexAtTarget)
        transmitPreviousImage(to:target, atIndex:indexAtTarget)
    } else {
        debugPrint("Warning: tried to add target beyond target's input capacity")
    }
}
```

**Edit** as other have said, the operator is custom to that project, and does not come builtin with the swift language as of Mar-29-2018

Answer (score 3):

The `-->` is a custom operator specific to that project, used to chain pipelines of functions together. It's defined in that project at [framework/Source/Pipeline.swift](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2/blob/23e20897bbcfd97fa901c9625e3a0a9cd3af46ba/framework/Source/Pipeline.swift) with an infix operator.